# Denote string values as specific numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to parse some data to a json file. One line is the language.

Since I want to save them in a database I want those values to be turned to number so lets say I have

```
Languages = [
  (1,'en'),
  (2,'fr'),
  (3,'de')
]
 
language = "en" # I want this to be equivalent to language = 1
```

How can I assign `language` with `1` instead of `'en'` ?

**EDIT**
I pick those values from an array so it would be something like

```
language = row[2] # Which is 'en'
```

I want that to be saved as `1`

Comment: Are you using Django? If so I know where are you going and I can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary instead of a list of tuples:

```py
Languages = {"en":1, "fr":2, "de":3}
language = Languages["en"]
print(language)
```

Result: `1`

Applied to your edit using rows:

```
language = Languages[row[2]]
```

Comment: Can you check my answer? Sry for the trouble I've edited it to better represent my problem. Thanks

Comment: @Brillios: I added that to the answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I have understood your question correctly, but, you want to map a string to a value, therefore, the correct way in python to do it is with a dictionary:

```
Languages = {"en" :  1, "fr" : 2}

language = Languages.get("en", 0)

# or in your case

language = Languages.get(row[0], 0)
```

if you get 0, then the language is not in the dictionary

Comment: Can you check my answer? Sry for the trouble I've edited it to better represent my problem. Thanks

Comment: just change Languages.get("en", 0), with Languages.get(row[0], 0)